# using NSInvocationOperation for UITableViewCell causes some UIImageViews to display the wrong image? Possible re-entrant issue?

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, nsoperation

I'm trying to keep my `UITableView` scrolling smoothly while going through about 700 pictures that are downloaded from the internet, cached (to internal storage) and displayed on each cell of the table. My code so far seems fine as far as scrolling performance. However, I noticed that sometimes, if the connection is being crappy or If I scroll really fast, a cell will display the wrong picture (that of another cell) for maybe about 1/2 a sec and then update to the image it is supposed to display.

I suspect 2 things so far:

A-
I might have a reentrancy issue from the point where my `NSInvocationOperation` calls back into the main thread with `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:]` to the point where the selector in the main thread gets executed. Though I don't really spot any shared variables.

B-
Some sort of race between the main thread and the `NSInvocationOperation`? Like:

1 main thread calls `cacheImageFromURL`

2 inside this call, `UIImage` spans the worker thread

3 worker thread is almost done and gets to call `performSelectorOnMainThread`

4 the cell in question is dequeued to be reused at this point, so main thread calls `cahceImageFromURL` again for a new image.

5 inside this call, UIImage stops the `NSOPerationQueue` which causes the previous `NSInvocationOperation` thread to die.

6 BUT, the thread had already called `performSelectorOnMainThread`

7 so the selector gets excited causing the old image to load.

8 immediately after this, the recently spawned thread is done fetching the new image and calls `performSelectorOnMainThread` again, causing the update to the right image.

If this is the case, I guess I'd need to set a flag on entry to the `cacheImageFromURL` method so that the worker thread code doesn't call `performSelectorOnMainThread` if there's another thread (the main one) already inside `cacheImageFromURL`?

Here's my code for my `UIImageView` subclass, which each cell in the table uses:

```
@implementation UIImageSmartView

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@synthesize defaultNotFoundImagePath;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - init
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)dealloc
{ 
  if(!opQueue)
  {
    [opQueue cancelAllOperations];
    [opQueue release];
  }
  [super dealloc];
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma mark - functionality
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (bool)cacheImageFromURL:(NSString*)imageURL
{
  /*  If using for the first time, create the thread queue and keep it 
      around until the object goes out of scope*/
  if(!opQueue)
    opQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
  else
    [opQueue cancelAllOperations];

  NSString *imageName = [[imageURL pathComponents] lastObject];
  NSString* cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
  NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

  /*  If the image is already cached, load it from the local cache dir.
      Else span a thread and go get it from the internets.*/
  if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachedImagePath])
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath]];
  else
  {
    [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:self.defaultNotFoundImagePath]];
    NSMutableArray *payload = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:imageURL, cachedImagePath, nil];

    /*  Dispatch thread*/
    concurrentOp = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadURI:) object:payload];
    [opQueue addOperation: concurrentOp];
    [concurrentOp release];
  }

  return YES;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*  Thread code*/
-(void)loadURI:(id)package
{
  NSArray *payload = (NSArray*)package;
  NSString *imageURL = [payload objectAtIndex:0];  
  NSString *cachedImagePath = [payload objectAtIndex:2];

  /*  Try fetching the image from the internets.
      If we got it, write it to disk. If fail, set the path to the not found again.*/
  UIImage *newThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];  
  if(!newThumbnail)
    cachedImagePath = defaultNotFoundImagePath;
  else  
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newThumbnail) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];

  /*  Call to the main thread - load the image from the cache directory
      at this point it'll be the recently downloaded one or the NOT FOUND one.*/
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImage:) withObject:cachedImagePath waitUntilDone:NO];
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void)updateImage:(NSString*)cachedImagePath
{
  [self setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath]];
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

And the way this UIImage is used is in the context of cellForRowAtIndexPath, like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIImageSmartView *cachedImage;
  // and some other stuff...

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) 
  {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;

    // some labels and tags stuff..

    cachedImage = [[UIImageSmartView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 57, 80)];
    cachedImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    cachedImage.defaultNotFoundImagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DefaultNotFound" ofType:@"png"];
    cachedImage.tag = PHOTO_TAG;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:cachedImage];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:secondLabel];

  }
  else
  {
    cachedImage = (UIImageSmartView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:PHOTO_TAG];
    mainLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:MAINLABEL_TAG]; 
  }

  // Configure the cell...

  NSString *ImageName = [[[self.dbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2] 
                         stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" 
                         withString:@"@57X80.png"];

  NSString *imageURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.aServerAddress.com/%@/thumbnail5780/%@", 
                        self.referencingTable, 
                        ImageName];

  [cachedImage cacheImageFromURL:imageURL];

  mainLabel.text = [[self.dbData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:0]; 
  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D33pN16h7 is right in that the problem was cell reuse. However, instead of trying to make the indexPath thread-safe through an NSURLConnection, I decided to reimplement the whole thing by moving the NSOperationQueue into the UITableViewController code and having the concurrent imageView class be actually a proper subclass of NSOperation (since I was using NSOperationInvocation in the first place to try and avoid the full-fledged NSOperation subclass).

So now, the table controller manages it's own NSOperationQueue, the operations are subclasses of NSOperation and I can cancel them from the table controller code as the table view scrolls past them. And everything works fast and nice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is reuse of cell, one cell makes the request of various images at same time, and is displaying when each one is downloaded, i know that you are canceling operations queue but as the processing caller is synchronous the operation continues the execution. I suggest try to save the indexPath of the request, and match it with the index path of the cell before set the UIImage.

Comment: trying to understand your suggestion. You mean, save the indexPath when entering cacheImageFromURL:, then passing it along to the NSInvocationOperation and have the NSInvocation pass it in turn back to the main thread code so that, on updateImage, if the current index path is not the same as the one passed along, not load the 'updated' image?

Comment: would it be better to just forget the whole NSOperationQueue and maybe go for a regular NSOperation instead? so that multiple requests cannot queue up and not get cancelled on time then?

Comment: Uhmm, let me explain me, try to add a property named indexPath to your UIImageSmartView object and set it every time in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, make a custom synchronous NSRLConnection (subclass) with a indexPath property, and when you make the request (NSOperationInvocation) set it to the current indexPath property of the UIImageSmartView, in this way you'll have a unique connection for each index. Before you set the image check if the indexPath of the UIImageSmartView matches with the indexPath of the custom NSURLConnection.